# Armature Not moving with object correctly

Tags: armature

[image]

So, when I move my armature in pose mode, its leg and parts aren't moving in unison with bone. I set deform and automatic weights, I also tried weight paint for separate vertex groups on the bones. Not sure what's wrong here

Comment: hello please share your file (remove the useless parts), upload and copy paste the URL: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like that area is affected by other unwanted bone(s). Try to select that area of the mesh in Edit mode than use Remove from all groups in the vertex group menu. Then go to Pose mode, select the leg bones, then go to Weight Paint mode and use Assign Automatic From Bones. In this way the other bones won't affect the result. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/editing.html#assign-automatic-from-bone

Comment: Thank you FFeller, I had 2 layers of vertex groups stacked on that area, I removed them and now it moves fine